# Comparing two tables and get the values that dont match

Tags: sql

I have two tables with articles.

table 1 `article` and table 2 `articlefm`

both tables have one field with `artnr`.

'table 1' has 2192 `artnr` and 'table 2' has 2195 `artnr`.

I want in my query to find out whats the `artnr` of the 3 articles that is not matched.

If 'table 2' has more articles then 'table 1' then I need a list with those `artnr`.

How can I make this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(t1.Artnr, t2.Artnr) AS Artnr,
        CASE WHEN t1.Artnr IS NULL THEN 'Table1' ELSE 'Table2' END AS MissingFrom
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        FULL JOIN Table2 AS t2  
            ON t1.Artnr = t2.Artnr
WHERE   t1.Artnr IS NULL
OR      t2.Artnr IS NULL;
```

Note, that just because there is a difference in the count of 3, it does not necessarily mean that there are only 3 records in one table missing from the other. Imagine the following:

```
Table1          Table2
------          -------
1               2
2               4
3               6
4
```

The difference in count is 1, but there are actually 2 records present in table1 that aren't in table2, and 1 in table2 that isn't in table1. Using the above full join method you would get a result like:

```
Artnr | MissingFrom
------+-------------
  1   |  Table1
  3   |  Table1
  6   |  Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

In most databases you can use `except` (SQL standard) or `minus` (Oracle specific):

```
select artnr
from   articlefm -- table 2
except
select artnr
from   article -- table 1
```

Else you could try a `not in`:

```
select atrnr
from   articlefm -- table 2
where  atrnr not in
       ( select artnr
         from   article -- table 1
       )
```

This will give you the article numbers that exist in 2, but not in 1.

Comment: `except` is the operator defined by the SQL standard. `minus` is what Oracle is using.