# How to compare data from two databases

Tags: sql

I have two databases for two different stores. They have the same tables and structure.

When I created the second one, I made a copy of the first one and I'm pretty sure that I forgot to delete some data from the first one before I activated the second one.

Now I need to find this data and delete it from db two because I have for example articles from store 1 in store 2's database.

Is there some easy way to identify the data that is in both databases?

Comment: Probably, but without some hint as to the structure of your tables, it is going to be hard for anyone to help.

Comment: You can also use VisualStudio and data compare. Is really easy wizzard. For example VisualStudio 2012 or SQL Server data tools for visual studio 2013

Comment: You could use VisualStudio, but it isn't really a db tool. If the db is designed properly, you can do this with a left join and where ... is null type statement. Also, did OP say he was on windows and using SQL Server. To be fair, OP didn't really tell us anything useful, but suggesting specific tools on back of no info isn't helpful either.

Comment: Yea, if these database have too many records i dont recomended VisualStudio. And i agree with John Barca. You can easy create linked servers... in your new database and create compare selects with left join...

Comment: What rdbms are you using? what are the columns in the tables?

Comment: Wait, is this the same question you have asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402379/comparing-two-tables-and-get-the-values-that-dont-match

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: It's Mysql databases and im using HeidiSQL. Donal that was another Problem. What i can do is i can copy articles table from db 1 to db 2 and then make a query to find the matches but that would take me a lot of time to do that for every table.

Comment: in oracle we have merge statement, look if it is available for Mysql or not

Comment: Try SQL Delta, it will show you the differences in schema as well as records

Answer (score 0):

So i find one way but this would cost me a lot of time.

In heidisql that i use i made a copy of the article table in db 1 and put it in db 2 with the Name article_db1

Then i made a SELECT * FROM article a INNER JOIN article_db1 ON a.artnr = b.artnr and like this i got the matches that is in both databases.

My Problem is that im afraid i have to do this on all 40 tables in the databases and becuase of that i was thinking that it's maybe some faster way to solve this.